# Validar arquivo xml antes de atualizar banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Tenho um sistema de upload de arquivo que ao enviar o arquivo xml ele envia as inserções e atualizações no banco de dados, mas caso seja enviado um arquivo com a estrutura diferente recebo erros. Já encontrei algumas soluções utilizando [DTD](http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp) e [xml schemas](http://www.dicas-l.com.br/arquivo/tutorial_xml-schema.php#.VP-j_fnF-fd), mas mesmo assim estou um pouco confuso já que os exemplos não utilizam a mesma estrutura do arquivo que recebo.

Como posso garantir que o arquivo enviado tenha realmente a estrutura desejada utilizando php e mysql?

Segue exemplo do arquivo xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
    <row>
        <column>
            131290444
        </column>
        <column>
            Nome Completo
        </column>
        <column>
            10/09/1991
        </column>
        <column>
            39077161830
        </column>
        <column>
            email@email.com
        </column>
        <column>
            Aluno Regularmente Matriculado
        </column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>
            151290202
        </column>
        <column>
            Nome completo 2
        </column>
        <column>
            20/09/1987
        </column>
        <column>
            37999131814
        </column>
        <column>
            email2@email.com
        </column>
        <column>
            Aluno Regularmente Matriculado
        </column>
    </row>
</table>
```

Comment: O que você quer testar na estrutura? Os nomes dos nós, a posição deles, quantidade, tipo de valores...?

Comment: @RicardoBRGWeb Preciso validar a estrutura (cada row com 6 column) e o tipo de dados de cada cada column

Answer (score 1):

Para trabalhar com XML no PHP eu gosto de usar as classes XMLReader e XMLWriter porque elas processam nó por nó ao invés de carregar tudo na memória como fazem outras classes de manipulação XML com PHP.

Sem usar o DTD ou XML Schema você pode usar o XMLReader para encontrar os nós e comparar com um padrão que você queira.

Exemplo -  verificar se cada row tem 6 colunas e verificar os dados de cada coluna

```
<?php
$error = array();
$xml_file = 'arquivo.xml';
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open($xml_file);
$r = 0;
while ($reader->read()){//enquanto tiver nós no xml
  if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'row'){ //acha um row
    $r++;
    $row = new XMLReader; //nova instância para ler o xml dentro do nó row
    $r = $reader->readOuterXML(); //pega todo o nó
    $row->xml($r); //e carrega o nó na nova instância xml
    $c = 0; 
     while ($row->read()){//enquanto tiver nós no row  
        if ($row->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name !== 'column'){//verifica se o nó é diferente de <column>
        $c++;
             $error[] = 'Nó ' . $c . ' do row ' . $r . ' diferente de column';
        }
        if ($row->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name !== 'column'){
        //encontramos uma coluna
        $c++;
            $conteudo = $row->readInnerXML(); //pega o conteúdo do nó
            //aqui você pode testar cada tipo de dado de acordo com o número do nó
        }
     }//acabaram os nós do row    
    if ($c !== 6) {
        $error[] = 'Row '.$r.'tem um total de '.$c.' colunas.';//se não tiver 6 colunas
  }
}//acabaram as rows
var_dump ($error); //dump dos erros 
?>
```

Isso é só um exemplo pra você começar, não testei. Mas dessa forma você consegue processar XMLs de qualquer tamanho sem consumir muitos recursos do seu servidor. Confere [XMLReader manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.xmlreader.php) para mais opções de funções.

Comment: Não conhecia essa classe. +1

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente ler seu arquivo e verificar a quantidade de colunas para cada item do seu XML:

```
$xmlFile = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<table>
    <row>
        <column>
            131290444
        </column>
        <column>
            Nome Completo
        </column>
        <column>
            10/09/1991
        </column>
        <column>
            39077161830
        </column>
        <column>
            email@email.com
        </column>
        <column>
            Aluno Regularmente Matriculado
        </column>
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>
            151290202
        </column>
        <column>
            Nome completo 2
        </column>
        <column>
            20/09/1987
        </column>
        <column>
            37999131814
        </column>
        <column>
            email2@email.com
        </column>
        <column>
            Aluno Regularmente Matriculado
        </column>
    </row>
</table>
EOF;

function verifyRolesInXMLFile($urlFile) {

    try {

           //lê o arquivo XML
             $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($urlFile);

           if (count($xml->row) != 2) {
              throw new Exception("Número de <rows> tem que ser 2, o total deu: ".count($xml->row));
           } 

           if (count($xml->row[0]->column) != 6) {
              throw new Exception("Número de <column> da primeira linha tem que ser 6, o total deu: ".count($xml->row[0]->column));
           } 

           if (count($xml->row[1]->column) != 6) {
              throw new Exception("Número de <column> da linha de baixo tem que ser 6, o total deu: ".count($xml->row[1]->column));
           } 
          echo $xml;
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
           echo $e->getMessage();
       }
}
//executa o método de verificação de colunas
verifyRolesInXMLFile($xmlFile);
```

## Veja a solução funcionando aqui